# Apparent contradiction in official rules for Kamisado?

Tags: kamisado

I have in front of me the official Rules of the Game for [Kamisado](http://www.burleygames.com/board-games/kamisado/). They make me wonder which player takes the opening move in a new round after filling from the left or the right.

1. The section "Filling from the Left or Rights" explains that the towers "can be set up in one of two ways, determined by the player who won the previous round. This player will be the Defender in the new round". So this would suggest that the player who lost the previous round takes the first turn in the next round. That's also what seems to be implemented e.g. in the online version at [Yucata](http://www.yucata.de/en/GameInfo/Kamisado).
2. However the description of [Figure 7(h)](http://www.boardspace.net/kamisado/english/RULES%20ENG.pdf) states that the "diagram shows the possible moves open to Alain with his purple Sumo dragon tower, should he decide to make his opening move with this tower". Alain has just gained a Sumo tower by winning a round, so this would suggest that the player who won the previous round takes the first turn in the next round. Only if Alain were to begin could he chose which tower to make his opening move with.

I suspect that 1. is the right answer but am not yet sure. Who knows better and can explain the apparently odd description for Figure 7(h)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add third fact from the official Rules (in the "Opening Moves" section):

(3). "In any round, the player that moves first is known as the Challenger. The other player is known as the Defender for that round."

This rule is "hidden" in the basic rules, not where expected - after Filling L/R. The facts (1) and (3) together suggest the option 1: the player who lost in the previous round takes the opening move. That convinced *me* (I had the same hesitation). There is the common sense also - the opening move is said to give considerable advantage, so the loosing player could recover and the match would prolong.

I guess the description for Figure 7(h) must be simply an overlook, and should instead read: "diagram shows the possible moves open to Alain with his purple Sumo dragon tower, if he gets the opportunity to make move with purple and if nothing is blocking the purple tower". Too complicated; the figure should have been taken from another match not to confuse people.

Comment: [This](http://www.appstore.com/kamisado) iOS app now also implements option 1 (in its latest version).